# Getting a large number (but not all) Wikipedia pages

Tags: python, algorithm, wikipedia

For a [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) project of mine, I want to download a large number of pages (say, 10000) at random from Wikipedia. Without downloading the entire XML dump, this is what I can think of:

1. Open a Wikipedia page
2. Parse the HTML for links in a Breadth First Search fashion and open each page
3. Recursively open links on the pages obtained in 2

In steps 2 and 3, I will quit, if I have reached the number of pages I want.

How would you do it? Please suggest better ideas you can think of.

ANSWER: This is my Python code:

```
# Get 10000 random pages from Wikipedia.
import urllib2
import os
import shutil
#Make the directory to store the HTML pages.
print "Deleting the old randompages directory"
shutil.rmtree('randompages')

print "Created the directory for storing the pages"
os.mkdir('randompages')

num_page = raw_input('Number of pages to retrieve:: ')

for i in range(0, int(num_page)):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    infile = opener.open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random')

    page = infile.read()

    # Write it to a file.
    # TODO: Strip HTML from page
    f= open('randompages/file'+str(i)+'.html','w')
    f.write(page)
    f.close()

    print "Retrieved and saved page",i+1
```

Comment: Wikipedia don't allow you to download its pages directly using a bot, you'll just get 1000 'error pages'. Choose another site ;-)

Comment: Ups, nice trick adding the 'User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0' to allow the download. Anyway, don't download automatically pages from Wikipedia, they don't like that...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
for i = 1 to 10000
    get "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"
```

Comment: Though this can give duplicates, it won't probably matter much for me. +1 for the quick simple thought.

Comment: My comment above applies ;-) Wikipedia won't allow you, you'll end with 10000 error pages.

Answer (score 20):

Wikipedia has an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php). With this API you can get any random article in a given namespace:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&rnnamespace=0&rnlimit=5
```

and for each article you call also get the wiki text:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Main%20Page&rvprop=content
```

Comment: Do you have any experience with using the API in Python? Any Python libraries?

Comment: The API returns data as JSON or XML. So I guess any language is able to parse this kind of structured data. You will also find many libraries here : http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_Code#Python

Comment: Thanks Pierre. Your answer is correct too, but I accepted Tommy's answer since i did not need any modifications to my existing code for doing what I wanted to do. Sorry.

Comment: @Pierre: IS the API available in c#?

Comment: That's a REST API, so you can use it with any language as long as you can access the web and parse JSON or XML...

Answer (score 1):

I'd go the opposite way-- start with the XML dump, and then throw away what you don't want.

In your case, if you are looking to do natural language processing, I would assume that you are interested in pages that have complete sentences, and not lists of links.  If you spider the links in the manner you describe, you'll be hitting a lot of link pages.

And why avoid the XML, when you get the benefit of using XML parsing tools that will make your selection process easier?

Comment: Because it's multiple terabytes, uncompressed.